# How do you make an image that you can click, but not any area around the image?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

For example, currently if I put the image in a label or picture box and want the user to click the image the transparent background is also clickable, which I don't want because otherwise the 'hitboxes' of the several images I am putting in will overlap.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could try to GetPixel the clicked color and only process non-transparent pixels.

Answer (score -2):

You can determine if the Click-Position is within the Picturebox-Image-Size.

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (((MouseEventArgs)e).X <= pictureBox1.Image.Width &&
        ((MouseEventArgs)e).Y <= pictureBox1.Image.Height)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Valid Click");
    }
}
```

If the position of the image in the Picturebox is not at 0/0 you have to pay attention to that.

Comment: The question is not very long, but apparently you missed a key point: *"the transparent background is also clickable, which I don't want"*.

Comment: Well the question is not very clear: is the transparent background all around the picture in the picturebox or transparent pixels inside the image itself?

Comment: If you think it's unclear, ask instead of answering.

Comment: I need 50 reputation to add a comment.

Comment: Since the question has already been closed I suggest you delete this answer to avoid further reputation loss.

Comment: No, I like my answer. Mistakes are here to learn. Also a Pciturebox can display a single image at the same time only so the logical conclusion of the question is, how to click that image in the Picturebox only and everything around the image is the transparent background. But nevermind...

Comment: *"Mistakes are here to learn"* Fair enough. I still think the question was about transparent portions inside of the image (gif/png) but unfortunately we'll probably never know, seeing how responsive OP is.

Comment: That's true. And if someone wants to make transparent pixels unclickable there is the duplicate answer and for people who want to click image only but not the whole Picturebox, there is a wrong answer here. Have a nice day.